# Find number of element in series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I have $x_n = \frac{n^2 + \sqrt{n}\sin n}{n^2 + \cos (n^3)}$.

I know that its limit is $1$, but how to find number of element $N_\epsilon$ from which the inequality $|x_n - A| < \epsilon$ holds $\forall n > N_\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use that approach, but if you want to: for all $n > N > 1$:

$$|x_n- 1|= \frac{| \sqrt n \sin(n) - \cos(n^3)|}{n^2 + \cos(n^3)} < \frac{|\sqrt n \sin(n)| + 1}{n^2 - 1} < \frac{n+1}{n^2  -1}=\frac {1}{n-1}
\leq \frac{1}{N}$$

So $N_\varepsilon = 1/\varepsilon$ will do.

The better way to go about this is the sandwich (or squeeze) theorem though: $l_n = \frac{n^2 - n}{n^2 + 1} < x_n < u_n = \frac{n^2 + n}{n^2 - 1}$ for all $n>1$ and the upper and lower bounds $l_n$ and $u_n$ both converge to 1.